# Showing that $\|1\| = 1.$

Tags: banach-algebras

> Let $A$ be a Banach algebra. A map $a \mapsto a^*$ is called an involution if for all $a,b \in A$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb C,$
>
> $(1)$ $(a^*)^* = a,$
>
> $(2)$ $(a + b)^* = a^* + b^*,$
>
> $(3)$ $(\lambda a)^* = \overline {\lambda}\ a^*,$
>
> $(4)$ $(ab)^* = b^* a^*.$
>
> A Banach algebra $A$ with an involution is called a $C^*$-algebra if $\|a^* a\| = \|a\|^2.$

With the above definition in mind I am trying to prove the following exercise $:$

> $\textbf {Exercise} :$ Let $A$ be a unital $C^*$-algebra. Show that $\|1\| = 1.$

If we can somehow show that $1^* = 1$ then by the definition of $C^*$-algebra we are through. But I am struggling to prove this. Could anyone please give me some small hint in this regard?

Thanks a bunch.

Comment: Use (4): set $a=1$ or $b=1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From *Operator Theoretic Aspects of Ergodic Theory*, page 509:

> An **involution** on a complex Banach algebra $A$ is a map $x \mapsto x*$ satisfying
> $$
> (x^*)^* = x, \quad (x+y)^* = x^* + y^*, \quad (\lambda x)^* = \bar{\lambda}x^*, \quad (xy)^* = y^*x^*
> $$
> for all $x, y \in A$, $\lambda \in \mathbb{C}$. In an algebra with involution one has $e^* = e$ since
> $$
> e^* = e^*e = (e^*e)^{**} = (e^*e^{**})^* = (e^*e)^* = (e^*)^* = e.
> $$

Answer (score 0):

To see that $1^*=1$, it suffices to show that $1^*a=a=a1^*$. This is easy:

$$1^*a=(a^*1)^*= a^{**}=a$$
and similarly $a1^*=a$.

Then note that

$\|1\|=\|1^*1\|=\|1\|^2$ whence $\|1\|=0$ or $\|1\|=1$. If $\|1\|=0$, then $1=0$ and the algebra is trivial, i.e. $A=\{0\}$. In all other cases, the norm of the unit is $1$.